# The sum of the values of a for which $\frac{x^3-6x^2+11x-6}{x^3+x^2-10x+8} + \frac a{30} = 0$ does not have a real solution is

Tags: quadratics

The sum of the values of a for which $$\frac{x^3-6x^2+11x-6}{x^3+x^2-10x+8} + \frac a{30} = 0$$ does not have a real solution is

**A.** $1$

**B.** $12$

**C.** $13$

**D.** $2$

I tried to factorise the numerator and the denominator and got
$$\frac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}{(x-1)(x-2)(x+4)}$$
Then $f(x) = \frac{x-3}{x+4}$, but after this how to get the range of $f(x)$?

Any help will be appreciated ....thanks.

Comment: It is unreadable.

Comment: Is that supposed to be $$\dfrac{x^3-6x^2+11x-6}{x^3+x^2-10x+8} + \frac{a}{30}$$? If not, then what?

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes it is

Comment: @NeetuYadav Are you sure the problem statement is completely accurate? I'm suspecting a sign flip somewhere...

Comment: @user3733558 question is proper ...no sign issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take
$$y=f(x) = \frac{x-3}{x+4}$$
Then,
$$\frac{y+1}{y-1}=\frac{2x+1}{-7}$$
or
$$x=\frac 1 2 \left(\frac{7y+7}{1-y}-1\right)$$
So, the range is $\mathbb R \backslash \{1\}$ because $x$ is defined iff $y\neq 1$.

Now, check that $y=-\frac{12}{30}$ gives $x=1$, for which the original fraction takes $\frac 0 0$ form. So, $a\neq 12$. Also, we can see that $a\neq -30$ because $y\neq 1$. Again, $a\neq 5$ because $y\neq -\frac 1 6$ (as that would imply $x=2$ which is not possible). Summing these up, we aren't getting $13$, we are getting $-13$. So, I think the option has a sign flip.

Does that help?

Comment: Answer is not 12 it is 13

Comment: you have not find out the range values

Comment: @NeetuYadav You don't need the range of $f(x)$. You only need the value of $a$ for which $\frac{x^3-6x^2+11x-6}{x^3+x^2-10x+8} + \frac a{30} = 0$ does not have a real solution. And, if the answer given is **C**, then it's wrong. You can check that $x=\frac{38}{43}$ is a solution of $\frac{x^3-6x^2+11x-6}{x^3+x^2-10x+8} + \frac {13}{30} = 0$. Also, I proved **B** in my solution above.

Comment: $a=12$ appears to work, yes. But the problem statement asks for "the **sum** of the values of $a$ for which...". Is $a=12$ the only one possibility?

Comment: @SayanDutta it is not asking value of a it is asking sum of values of a and it is 13

Comment: @user3733558 ur right ...it is asking sum of values of a......and it is 13

Comment: @SayanDutta you will get 3 three different  of value of a  and then you have to add three value and that is a result

Comment: @user3733558 Oh! It was sum? I didn't notice that. Just a moment.

Comment: @NeetuYadav The range as you can see is $\mathbb R \backslash \{1\}$ because look at the expression of $x$ as a function of $y$ and note that $x$ is defined iff $y\neq 1$.

Comment: @NeetuYadav I can see that $a\neq -30$ because $y\neq 1$. Also, $a\neq 5$ because $y\neq -\frac 1 6$ (as that would imply $x=2$ which is not possible). Still, summing these up, you aren't getting $13$, you are getting $-13$. So, I think the option has a sign flip.

Comment: I did the edits. Thanks for pointing the mistake out. Please check whether it's okay now.

Comment: @SayanDutta can u tell me how 1 is excluded from range? range = R- {1,-2,5 ,-1/6}

Comment: @SayanDutta why 1 is excluded from Real ?

Comment: @NeetuYadav You have $x=\frac 1 2 \left(\frac{7y+7}{1-y}-1\right)$. See that $y=1$ is the only value for which $\frac 1 2 \left(\frac{7y+7}{1-y}-1\right)$ is not defined. So, there is no $x$ for which $y=1$. That is why, $\{1\}$ is not in the range. Is that clear now?

Comment: @SayanDutta okk....understood

Comment: @SayanDutta how did you got y+1/y-1 = 2x+1/-7  ?

Comment: It's componendo dividendo. Check this out - https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/

Comment: @SayanDutta okkkk